# Need help parsing xml with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing

> First let me thank you for the assistance, I am new to Javascript, and want to learn to    parse  a >.xml file into my javascript. The file I want to parse is contact.xml, located in my root   folder.
>   Again, thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1     /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(XMLname)
{
var xmlDoc;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xmlDoc.open("GET",XMLname,false);
xmlDoc.send("");
return xmlDoc.responseXML;
}
// IE 5 and IE 6
else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))
{
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async=false;
xmlDoc.load(XMLname);
return xmlDoc;
}
alert("Error loading document!");
return null;
}
<title>Contacts</title>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("contactinfo.xml") // Path to the XML file;
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (i=0;i<M.length;i++){
document.write("<div style='width:450px;'>")
document.write("<h2>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</h2>");
document.write("<p>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("servicephone")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+    "</p>");
document.write("<p><a href='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("email")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue   +"</p>);
document.write("</div>")
}
</script>

</body>
</html>


*Here is my .xml file*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Contacts>
<item servicephone="(800) 500-0066" 
email="customerservice@fsig.com" 
url="http://www.fsig.com" 
address="5000 Barcilona Beach Rd. Wilmington, NC 28000">
</item>
</Contacts>
```

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them, and explain what the problem is. Posting a wall of code with "need help" and nothing else is not going to help.

Comment: @marc I apologize. The main issue of my problem is than I am getting a white screen instead of the information in the .xml. So my question is basically, in looking at my coding, where can i improve it so that I return the proper information from the contactinfo.xml file?

Comment: Start with some debugging, things like seeing what `M.length` is. Right now your script has NO visible output except what the javascript should be generating. Then start backtracking and figure out why it's 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go down the hierarchy, so, first find the `Contacts` node, then inside there you can get all the tagnames as you have.

You have a great deal of attributes so you may find this useful also:

```
node.attributes["url"].nodeValue
```

So just loop through all the items, then I would just copy `itemelem[t]` to `node` just to make it easier, then you get the attributes you need.

Depending on the browser you are using most of them come with some javascript debugger, so you can put in breakpoints and look at the values in the variables and see what the next step needs to be.